# How to confirm mysql-mariadb database migration is OK?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-migration

I've recently migrated databases (from a Ubuntu server) to a mariadb database (on a CentOS7 server) using 'mysqldump' and them importing with the 'mysql' command. I have this setup a a phpmyadmin environment and although the migration appears to have been successful, I've noticed phpmyadmin is reporting different disk space used and also showing slightly different row numbers for some of the tables.

Is there any way to determine if anything has been 'missed' or any way to confirm the data has all been copied across with the migration?
I've run a mysqlcheck on both servers to check db consistency but I don't think this really confirms the data is the same.

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: Just like any other database migration projects: reconcile the source data with the target.

Comment: I'm new to databases - this is my first attempt at a migration and I have to be honest and say I have no idea what you mean by that. If you have any examples of what that entails, that would be great.

Comment: If you do not have much data, then simply compare the data in the two databases with each other.

Comment: Unfortunately we're talking about a fairly sizable database. Some of the tables have > 100 million rows and a few tables have > 1 billion rows. Comparing that data might be difficult. Looking around in phpmyadmin, I've noticed that if I select a table and jump to the very last displayed rows it reports the number of rows up the top - whilst this is going to be a laborious task, I should be able to confirm the number of rows for all the databases.

Comment: Number of rows is one thing, what data you have in them is another. In this case compare totals on numeric columns, list of distinct values and counts by distinct values by textual columns, date ranges for date columns. Although I'm very surprised that if you have so many records, then why don't you have sy on your team, who has done a migration before...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a problem.

InnoDB, when using `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, gives you only an approximation of the number of rows.

The dump and reload rebuilt the data and the indexes.  This is very likely to lead to files of different sizes, even if the *logical* contents is identical.

Do you have any clues of discrepancies other than what you mentioned?

Comment: Rick - no clues to suggest there's a discrepancy but if there was a way to confirm the data I'd feel better.

Comment: See of `pt-table-checksum` provides what you need.